# Issue with opening a .js extension file in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed the latest version of the VS code and then opened the project folder in it till here it works fine , but when I try to open a .js file I get the below error as shown in image, but i'm able to open and add .ts,.text,.html.  The issue somehow seems to be just for .js files that i'm trying to add new,already existing js files are working fine for edit

[image]

I tried to reinstalling vs code  it didnt help. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: looks like there is not much content in `app.js`

Comment: got it sorted ,it was an issue with the anti-virus it was blocking all the files with .js from opening